# How to use int i= cat_iamgeId instead of int i=0

Tags: ios, sqlite, tags, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have id value and product_image value in database. Image is associated with id value. I'm setting productimg_array image values to buttons for click. SO, here i need to set the id value to this button.So, i'm uisng for loop. If i use int i=0 the images are displaying, but if i set int i= cat_iamgeId the images are not displaying. Why?

```
productimg_array = [[NSMutableArray array]init];

       cat_imageidArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


        const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image,order_by,description FROM product where cat_id = ?";

        NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.




            if (sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, categoryId) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSLog(@"%s: bind failed: %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));


            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {


                cat_iamgeId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);


                NSLog(@"cat_iamgeId is %ld",(long)cat_iamgeId);

                [cat_imageidArray addObject:@(cat_iamgeId)];


                product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                 (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                NSLog(@"product_image is %@",product_image);

                [productimg_array addObject:product_image];


              NSLog(@"productimg_array %@", productimg_array);



           }


        }
```

For loop for UIButton click:

```
//   for (int i = 0; i<[productimg_array count]; i++ ) {


              for (int i = cat_iamgeId; i<[productimg_array count]; i++ ) {


           NSLog(@"productimg_array_index %@", productimg_array[i]);


                imgView1=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+(i*74), 0, 72, 72)];

                Width = Width + 20+(i*74);


              //  tag=[[cat_imageidArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue];

                imgView1.tag=i;


                  NSLog(@"product id is %ld ", (long)imgView1.tag);


                [imgView1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dbsofaClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


                [imgView1 setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];



                [scrollview addSubview:imgView1];


    }
```